# How to set a background image from the public folder in React (Create React App)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

I'm trying to set a background-img in a .css file created in src folde

> src/Components/Component/Comp.css

```
.services {
  background-image   : url("./images/img-2.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size    : cover;
  background-repeat  : no-repeat;
  color              : #fff;
  font-size          : 100px;
}
```

I received the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\react\react-website\src\images\img-1.jpg'
```

For fix it i copied images folder from public to src and it worked fine but now if I want to access those images in that path in a React Component. Ex:

> src/Components/Cards/Cards.js

```
<CardItem
src="./images/img-9.jpg"
text="Explore the hidden waterfall deep inside the Amazon jungle"
label="Adventure"
path="/services"
/>
```

> src/Components/Cards/CardItem.js

```
const { src, text, label, path } = props

    return (
        <>
            <li className="cards__item">
                <Link className="cards__item__link" to={path}>
                    <figure className="cards__item__pic-wrap" data-category={label}>
                        <img src={ src } alt="Travel" className="cards__item__img" />
                    </figure>
                    <div className="cards__item__info">
                        <h5 className="cards__item__text">{text}</h5>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </li>
        </>
    )
```

I don't receive any error but the image simple doesn't appears.

> **Where would I keep the images folder and how access to resources from .css and .js files correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to import image in your component then you can display image in the following way

```
var imageName = require('./images/img-9.jpg')
<img src={imageName} />
```

Here, require used for static "imports", so you need to change your imports.

But you can also do this in the following way

```
import imageName from './images/img-9.jpg';
<img src={imageName} />
```

This is another approach to do this

Answer (score 0):

Because your file is located at `src/Components/Component/Comp.css` and the image is located in the public folder. You will need to go 3 level up from the `Comp.css` file in order to select the image. You need to do something like this, this will most likely work and your IDE will most likely help you with the path by suggesting it as well:

```
<CardItem
src="../../../public/images/img-9.jpg"
/>
```

**However**, in an ideal scenario, you should not place the images inside the public folder, instead it is better to create an `assets` folder inside your `src` and then an `images` folder within the `assets` and place your image inside the `images` folder.

**The path in the a case would be:**

```
../../assets/images/img-9.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
const { src, text, label, path } = props

    // How I needed a dinamic solution for reuse the component, here i assign the src value and complete path to a const.
    //IMPORTANT: It is an object so we have to access to default property
    const imgSrc = require(`../../assets/images/${src}`).default

    return (
        <>
            <li className="cards__item">
                <Link className="cards__item__link" to={path}>
                    <figure className="cards__item__pic-wrap" data-category={label}>
                        <img src={imgSrc} alt="Travel" className="cards__item__img" />
                    </figure>
                    <div className="cards__item__info">
                        <h5 className="cards__item__text">{text}</h5>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </li>
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of 2021, this is still an ongoing discussion and a very confusing issue at related repo. (For those who are using up to date version of CRA)

Seems like one single commit was the reason of all these mess (Pretty interesting story actually, you can meet this "famous guy" there in this discussion.) Check out [here.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9937)

For those who stopped by here because of the same issue and if some other solutions are not working for you, best practice seems like to move all images into src folder. It is not a great solution and not useful in some cases, but still, seems like that's the best option we have so far.

Personally I have created a folder under src as : src/assets/images

And moved all my images there. In JSX files, to be able to use any image in this folder, we need to import it first like so (The path of yours may vary) :

```
import deleteModalIcon from '../../../assets/images/delete_modal_icon.svg'
```

Then, I could use it like so :

```
<img src={deleteModalIcon} alt='' />
```

In my css file which is located at top level of src folder, to be able to use an image, I did this :

```
.name:after {content: url('assets/images/edit_icon.svg');}
```

Please note that there are some complains there in this discussion about disappearing images after the build.

For people who will be reading this in the future: if there is a solid solution or an official fix for that issue at your time, please let me know in comments =)